# UISearchController search for struct array inside a Struct

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have 2 structs which takes, in a list of Courses.

```
struct Course : Decodable {
let CourseName : String;
let EntryRequirements : String;
}

struct  WebsiteDescription : Decodable {
let FullProgramName :String
let ProgramName : String;
let Courses : [Course]
}
```

These structs are loaded with JSON

I've implemented a UISearchController to actually Search through the Course Name.

I have no idea how to reference to the Struct Course from within the WebsiteDescription which contains the course names.

Arrays that I had used to contain the WebsiteDescription

```
  var allCourses = [WebsiteDescription]()
  var filteredCourses = [WebsiteDescription]()
```

I have tried to filter it with this method

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
        filteredCourses = allCourses
        acTableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        filteredCourses = allCourses.filter { $0.ProgramName.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) }



    }  
    self.acTableView.reloadData();
}
```

It filters the general programme name, but I would actually want to filter using the CourseName in the struct Course.

Thank you in advance.

[This is what I currently get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPYOh.jpg)

When I search for mentoring, the whole section of ShortCourses Appears when only 'Mentoring' should appear.

Mentoring is the Course Name

Comment: is allCourses array of  WebsiteDescription ?

Comment: yes, it is an array of WebsiteDescription

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
allCourses.filter { $0.ProgramName.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased())
```

with this

```
allCourses.filter {
             !$0.Courses.filter{$0.CourseName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchController.searchBar.text!)}.isEmpty
        }
```

It will give the result according to your `CourseName` in the struct `Course`.

**EDIT : It will give you `Array` of `Course`**

```
allCourses.flatMap{$0.Courses.filter{$0.CourseName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchController.searchBar.text!)}}
```

Comment: Hi! It works now but it returns the entire section, how do I only show the Course Name?

Comment: Okay. Do you want [Course] or [CourseName] as a result?

Comment: Course Name, please

Comment: There was an error encountered 'flatMap' produces '[String]', not the expected contextual result type '[WebsiteDescription]'

Comment: Exactly. This is an array for string , which is course name , as per you asked. not the array of WebsiteDescription. Can you show me pictorial representation, what you really want?

Comment: So I suppose, it was [Course] that I needed?

Comment: Change filteredCourses to ---   var filteredCourses = [Course]()